# How to call in VSTO build in function after were overwritten?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

In my Ribbon.xml is given:

```
<command idMso="FileSave" onAction="SaveIntercept" getEnabled="IsSaveInterceptEnabled" />
```

in my Ribbon.cs

```
public void SaveIntercept(IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
{
  if (!IsFileSavedBefore()) <= works :)
  {
    call here build in FileSave 
    (Build in function switch tab when file was never saved before)
    return;
  }
... File was saved before ... continue with my code

}
```

I already try

```
RibbonUi.ActivateTabMso("TabSave");
```

and

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FileSave");
```

How call origial functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work?

```
public void SaveIntercept(IRibbonControl control, ref bool cancelDefault)
{
  if (!IsFileSavedBefore())
  {
    cancelDefault = false;
    return;
  }
  ...
```